# How to return temp data to method in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult CCEEvaluationBlukUpload(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
        {
            ViewBag.Subjects = BindSubjects(BranchID, ClassID, BranchSectionID);
}



 public TempDataDictionary BindSubjects(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
        {
                  var  data = db.GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher((int?)dts.PersonalID, BranchID, dts.AcademicYearID, ClassID).ToList();
                  TempData["result"] = data;

            return TempData["result"];

        }
```

HI friends, in the above code i am calling a method BindSubjects with parameters. In bind method it will execute the result and store the data in tempdata and return the tempdata, but i dont know how to return the temp data to after execute that method. please help me how to return the result to viewbag.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing now ?

Comment: how to return tempdata? after execute the BindSubject method

Comment: Looking at the code I can understand that all you need is to save the `subject details` into your `Viewbag.Subjects` right?

Comment: yes...i want the data  in viewbag.subjects

Comment: directly return the `data` variable like `return data;` and change the Return type of your `BindSubjects` method to match the datatype of your data. you dont need to use TempData at all.

Comment: Then which return type i have to use..?

Comment: what ever type this method `GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher` returns.

Comment: actually i am using two different type store procedure using if and else.. then how can i use two different type of class...?

Comment: so in that case you can just make it a `object` since every type in C# ultimately derives from `object`.

Comment: why to return tempdata when you can return data itself..

Answer (score 0):

better to use object or dynamic type instead of temData["result"]

Comment: public dynamic BindSubjects(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
        {
                  dynamic data = 
   
   
 db.GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher((int?)dts.PersonalID, BranchID, dts.AcademicYearID, ClassID).ToList();

            return data;

        }

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to return the result as `ViewBag`, why are you assigning to `TempData` in the first place. You can either do this:

```
ViewBag.Subjects = db.GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher((int?)dts.PersonalID, BranchID, dts.AcademicYearID, ClassID).ToList();
```

Or this:

```
TempData["result"] = db.GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher((int?)dts.PersonalID, BranchID, dts.AcademicYearID, ClassID).ToList();
```

in your `CCEEvaluationBlukUpload` controller.

In your View, you can check the result as:

```
@if(ViewBag.Subjects != null)
{
//code goes here
}
```

Or this:

```
@if(TempData["result"] != null)
{
//code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option in case you don't want to waste memory.

```
public ActionResult CCEEvaluationBlukUpload(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
{
    var subjects = BindSubjects(BranchID, ClassID, BranchSectionID);
}



private List<GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher> BindSubjects(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
{
    return db.GetAcademicStaffSubjectDetailsByClassTeacher((int?)dts.PersonalID, BranchID, dts.AcademicYearID, ClassID).ToList();
}
```

And if you really want to use TempData, then add a line:

```
public ActionResult CCEEvaluationBlukUpload(int BranchID, int ClassID, int BranchSectionID)
{
    var subjects = BindSubjects(BranchID, ClassID, BranchSectionID);
    TempData["result"] = subjects;
}
```

Comment: If there have multiple storeprocedures then how we can write return type..?

Comment: By assumption, I guess you have to create your own ViewModel based on your requirements. But for that, you've to show some code regarding what you want to achieve.